# Swift TableView SearchDisplayController EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchdisplaycontroller, exc-bad-instruction

I have a TableView with Persons. When I tap on a cell it performs a seque to another view.

Searching works. But when I search, cancel, tap on one cell, go back and want to search again, it crashes. EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    var cell = UITableViewCell()


    if let sdc = self.searchDisplayController {

        if sdc.active {

        if let c: AnyObject? = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellPerson"){


            cell = c as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel.text = personsFiltered[indexPath.row]! 

            }
            else
            {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            }


        } else {

        if let c: AnyObject? = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellPerson"){


            cell = c as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel.text = persons[indexPath.row]! 

            }
            else
            {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            }

    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: And where exactly does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what is causing the crash without further details of exactly where it is happening but the problem may be around the dequeuing lines from self.tableView. In this delegate call back `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath`  the tableView parameter may be from the searchDisplayController or the backing TableViewController. To ensure you dequeue from the correct tableView change `self.tableView` to `tableView`.

Also keep in mind that the `UISearchDisplayController` has been deprecated in iOS 8 to be replaced by `UISearchController` so if this is not related to that you many have other trouble soon.

Comment: I tried to change it, but it didn't work. 

Yes, but I want to support iOS 7 too.